# Python cannot recognize PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have installed python 3.6.2, Mysql 6.3 and pyMySQL 0.7.11
When running the following scrip

```
import pymysql
import mysql.connector
class Crud:
def __init__(self):
    self.db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'dnsmonitor', 'test', 'DNSMON')
    self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
```

I get the following error

```
File "demo.py", line 1, in <module>
import pymysql
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'

What could be the root cause of this issue?
I'm running on windows 10

Comment: How did you install pymysql?

Comment: pip install pymysql

Comment: You're not using a virtualenv?

Comment: Nop, I just run locally

Comment: It's difficult to conjecture what your problem is, but if you use a virtualenv I'm pretty sure it'll work.

Comment: Maybe you have another python distribution installed? Try to install the module using `path\to\python3\pip install pymysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted in the question, I was using Python 3.6.2. 
Now I downgraded to Python 3.5.3 and that solved the problem.